# Why don't you have to initialize properties in Django models?

Tags: python, django

I'm starting off with Django, and I'm sort of confused about how the models work. I've searched for a bit and can't find an answer. When creating classes in Python, we have to initialize the object properties, for example:

```
class Contact(Object):
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
```

And if we create a subclass, for example, coworker:

```
Class Coworker(Contact):
     def __init__(self, name, number, title):
         Contact.__init__(self, name, number)
         self.title = title
```

So it makes sense that we still initialize the properties from the superclass, but in Django, why don't we do any initialization? We inherit from the models.Model class:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Why don't we have to initialize CharField from Model before we use it? I hope I'm not being too cryptic with my question. Like I said, I'm just getting started with Django, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they're stored in the database. Either the program or the manager will instantiate the model with the correct arguments, therefore it is inappropriate for the initializer to blatantly override them.

Answer (score 0):

```
def __init___(self, **kwargs):
    cls_ = type(self)
    for k in kwargs:
        if not hasattr(cls_, k):
            raise TypeError(
                "%r is an invalid keyword argument for %s" %
                (k, cls_.__name__))
        setattr(self, k, kwargs[k])
```

There should be an universal `__init__` method in `models.Model` like this (This is a snippet from SQLAlchemy but I believe that Django uses some similar methods)